# What is wrong with this implementation of quicksort algorithm? Error being RecursionError

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

```
def quicksort(array):
    print(array)
    n = 0
    pivot = len(array) - 1
    while n < pivot:
        if array[pivot] > array[n]:
            n+=1
        elif array[pivot] <= array[n]:
            array[n],array[pivot-1] = array[pivot-1], array[n]
            array[pivot],array[pivot-1] = array[pivot-1], array[pivot]
            pivot -= 1
    if len(array[:pivot]) >1:
        array[:pivot] = quicksort(array[:pivot])
    if len(array[pivot+1:])> 1:
        array[pivot+1:] = quicksort(array[pivot+1:])
    return array

test = [21, 4, 1, 3, 9, 20, 25, 6, 21, 14]
print(quicksort(test))
```

raises the following error:

```
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\idle.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(quicksort(test))
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\idle.py", line 14, in quicksort
    array[pivot:] = quicksort(array[pivot:])
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\idle.py", line 14, in quicksort
    array[pivot:] = quicksort(array[pivot:])
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\idle.py", line 12, in quicksort
    array[:pivot] = quicksort(array[:pivot])
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\idle.py", line 14, in quicksort
    array[pivot:] = quicksort(array[pivot:])
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\idle.py", line 14, in quicksort
    array[pivot:] = quicksort(array[pivot:])
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\idle.py", line 14, in quicksort
    array[pivot:] = quicksort(array[pivot:])
  [Previous line repeated 987 more times]
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\idle.py", line 3, in quicksort
    pivot = len(array) - 1
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Comment: An easy way to debug any recursive function is to print the function arguments at the top of the function. In other words, put a `print array` before `n = 0`

Comment: @phipsgabler ahh I dont see any identation problem. maybe some browser problem.

Comment: If the maximum recursion depth is exceeded, you recurse too much. That means that your conditions for recursion are wrong. At first glance, you don't seem to exclude the pivot from the subarrays when recursing -- `array[:pivot]` and `array[pivot:]` make up the full array. After partitioning, the pivot is in its correct place and should be excluded from the left and right subarrays.

Comment: @Sid Interesting... in my browser, the `def` and all function contents are indented at the same level, and with one space. Both of which Python would complain about.

Comment: `array[pivot:]` should be `array[pivot+1:]`. You don't need this subarray to include the pivot since the pivot is already in the right place.

Comment: @MOehm my bad i will change it to array[pivot+1 : ] but i still dont get the logic error. i mean am not sure but it is computable, atleast in the case of the test case

Comment: Thanks it was just the array[ pivot: ] problem which I overlooked.

Comment: The problem is with multiple elements, where you get `[21, 21]` for example and it is always partitioned into `[], [21, 21]`. You end up trying to partition `[21, 21]` repeatedly.

Comment: @MOehm yup I was just overlooking this thing even when I noticed it. Didn't thought about how it was messing the  algo. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
def quicksort(array):
    print(array)
    n = 0
    pivot = len(array) - 1
    while n < pivot:
        if array[pivot] > array[n]:
            n+=1
        elif array[pivot] <= array[n]:
            array[n],array[pivot-1] = array[pivot-1], array[n]
            array[pivot],array[pivot-1] = array[pivot-1], array[pivot]
            pivot -= 1
    if len(array[:pivot]) >1:
        array[:pivot] = quicksort(array[:pivot])
    if len(array[pivot+1:])> 1:
        array[pivot+1:] = quicksort(array[pivot+1:])
    return array

test = [21, 4, 1, 3, 9, 20, 25, 6, 21, 14]
print(quicksort(test))
```

It was just excluding pivot from the subarrays. So array[pivot:] becomes array[pivot+1: ]

Answer (score 1):

```
def quicksort(array):
print(array)
n = 0
pivot = len(array) - 1
while n < pivot:
    if array[pivot] > array[n]:
        n+=1
    elif array[pivot] <= array[n]:
        array[n],array[pivot-1] = array[pivot-1], array[n]
        array[pivot],array[pivot-1] = array[pivot-1], array[pivot]
        pivot -= 1
if len(array[:pivot]) >1:
    array[:pivot] = quicksort(array[:pivot])
if len(array[pivot:])> 1:
    array[pivot:] = quicksort(array[pivot:])
return array

test = [19, 4, 1, 3, 9, 20, 25, 6, 21, 14]
print(quicksort(test))
```

M Oehm is correct! I tried this modified code and it works on array with distinct elements. The output is:

```
[19, 4, 1, 3, 9, 20, 25, 6, 21, 14]
[6, 4, 1, 3, 9]
[6, 4, 1, 3]
[3, 4, 6]
[3, 4]
[14, 25, 20, 21, 19]
[19, 20, 21, 25]
[19, 20, 21]
[19, 20]
[1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 14, 19, 20, 21, 25]
```

- If you need a quick sort that works on array with repeated elements, you will have to partition it into 3 (instead of 2) subarrays `{{Xi}, {Xk}, {Xj}}`, where `{Xi}` is smaller than pivot, `{xk}=pivot` and `{Xj} > pivot`.

Comment: Why is splitting into 3 better?

Comment: I just want to say your edited code is absolutely correct! But considering that its performance is suboptimal if the your input array contains almost only identical elements (since each split will divide an n-element array into (n-1) and 1-element subarrays) . Hence, splitting into 3 will increase performance, as you do not have to split the `{Xk}` subarray which equals to pivot element any more.

Comment: Oh I see. Now I understand what @Ramin what was trying to explain too. Thanks!!